# Why am I getting a Redefinition of a C++ class error?

Tags: c++

Using the following code below I am getting a "Redefinition of SortedLL" error. 
So I removed "class SortedLL" from the header file below.  But when I remove SortedLL from the header file then I can't declare a SortedLL in the main.cpp file.

So I am stuck. What am I missing?

Sorted Linked List header file

```
#ifndef SortedLinkedList_SortedLL_h
#define SortedLinkedList_SortedLL_h

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node * next;
};

class SortedLL {
public:
    int find(int data);
    bool remove(int data);
    int size();
    bool removeOdd();
    bool add(int data);

private:
    struct Node * pHead;
    int length;
};

#endif
```

Sorted Linked List CPP file

```
#include <iostream>

#include "SortedLL.h"

class SortedLL {
private:


    // searches the linked list linearly
    int findLinear(int data, struct Node ** pPrev, struct Node ** pCurr){
        // start at head of list
        *pCurr = pHead;
        *pPrev = NULL;
        int index = 0;
        while (*pCurr != NULL){
            if ((*pCurr)->data == data){
                // found
                return index;
            }
            else {
                *pPrev = *pCurr;
                *pCurr = (*pCurr)->next;
                index++;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

     bool findInsertPointLinear(struct Node ** pPrev, struct Node ** pCurr, int data){ 
        while (*pCurr != NULL){

            // if current data is less then new data
            if ((*pCurr)->data < data){
                // store previous node
                *pPrev = *pCurr;

                // advance to next position
                *pCurr = (*pCurr)->next;
            }

            // current value is >= new val
            else {
                // we found insertion point
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }

    // returns the value at the index or NULL if no value exists
     bool get(int index, int * val) {

        // check if out of bounds
        if (index < 0 || index > (length-1)) {
            // out of bounds
            return false;
        }

            struct Node * pCurr = pHead;

            for (int i=0;i<=index;i++){
                pCurr = pCurr->next;
            }

            if (val != NULL) {
                *val = pCurr->data;
            }

            return true;
            }
public:
    bool add (int data) {
        struct Node * pCurr = pHead;
        struct Node * pPrev = NULL;
        bool returnVal = true;      

        // if the list is empty
        if (pHead == NULL){
            // add the new node
            pHead = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
            pHead->data = data;
            pHead->next = NULL;

            // return success
            length++;
            return returnVal;
        }

        // the list is not empty, so find insertion point
        if (findInsertPointLinear(&pPrev, &pCurr, data)){

            // if inserting at the begininng of list
            if (pPrev == NULL){
                pPrev = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                if (pPrev != NULL) {
                    pPrev->data = data;
                    pPrev->next = pCurr;

                    // keep track of head pointer
                    pHead = pPrev;
                }
                else {
                    // failed to allocate memory
                    returnVal = false;
                }
            }

            // if inserting at end of list
            else if (pCurr == NULL && pPrev !=NULL) {
                pCurr = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                if (pCurr != NULL){
                    pCurr->data = data;
                    pPrev->next = pCurr;
                    pCurr->next = NULL;
                }
                else {
                    // failure to allocate memory
                    returnVal = false;
                }
            }

            // if inserting in the middle of list
            else {
                pPrev->next = (struct Node *) malloc (sizeof(struct Node));
                if (pPrev->next != NULL){
                    pPrev->next->data = data;
                    pPrev->next->next = pCurr;
                }
                else {
                    // failure to allocate memory
                    returnVal = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // increment size of list by 1
        if (returnVal == true)
            length++;

        return returnVal;
    }

    // returns index of first occurrence of data or -1 if not found
     int find(int data){
        struct Node * pPrev = NULL;
        struct Node * pCurr = NULL;
        return findLinear(data, &pPrev, &pCurr);
    }








             bool remove(int data) {
                // try to find data
                struct Node * pPrev = NULL;
                struct Node * pCurr = NULL;
                int removeIndex = findLinear(data, &pPrev, &pCurr);
                 bool returnVal = false;
                // if found
                if (removeIndex != -1){
                    // remove node
                    return false;
                }

                // if removing at the head
                if (removeIndex == 0){
                    if (pCurr != NULL){
                        pHead = pCurr->next;
                        free(pCurr);
                        pCurr = NULL;
                        returnVal = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("trying to remove an element that does not exist\n");
                    }
                }

                // if removing at the end
                else if (removeIndex == (length-1)){
                    if (pCurr != NULL) {
                        free(pCurr);
                        pCurr = NULL;

                        if (pPrev != NULL){
                            pPrev->next = NULL;
                        }
                        returnVal = true;

                    }
                    else {
                        printf("trying to remove an element that does not exist\n");

                    }

                }

                // removing somewhere in the middle
                else {
                    if (pPrev != NULL && pCurr != NULL){
                        struct Node * temp = pCurr->next;
                        free(pCurr);
                        pCurr = NULL;
                        pPrev->next = temp;
                        returnVal = true;
                    }

                    // something is wrong
                    else {
                        printf("attempting to remove an element from middle but either previous or curr element is NULL\n");
                    }
                }

                return returnVal;
            }


             int size(){
                return length;
            }

             bool removeOdd(){
                struct Node * pCurr = pHead;
                struct Node * pPrev = NULL;


                // iterate over list
                while (pCurr != NULL){

                    // if current data element is odd
                    if (pCurr->data %2 != 0){
                        // remove it

                        // removing at head
                        if (pCurr == pHead){
                            pHead = pHead->next;
                            free(pCurr);
                            pCurr = pHead;

                        }

                        // if removing at the end
                        else if (pCurr->next == NULL){
                            free(pCurr);
                            pCurr = NULL;
                            pPrev->next = NULL;
                        }

                        // removing somewhere in the middle
                        else {
                            struct Node * temp = pCurr->next;
                            free(pCurr);
                            pPrev->next = temp;

                            // advance pCurr to next node
                            pCurr = temp;
                        }
                    }

                    // if current data element even
                    else {
                        pPrev = pCurr;
                        pCurr = pCurr->next;
                    }
                }

                 return true;
             }
}SortedLL;
```

Comment: You posted code that defines SortedLL in a header, you include the header, and then in your CPP file, you define it again.  Don't know how much simpler to explain your error.

Comment: @user1068636: That's exactly what you have. Your `.cpp` contains a redefinition of the class `SortedLL` right there in plain view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ PaulMcKenzie points out, you've defined the class SortedLL in both your header and your .cpp file. What you want in the .cpp is just the method definitions. Something like:

```
int SortedLL ::findLinear(int data, struct Node ** pPrev, struct Node ** pCurr) {
   ...
}
```